# How to delete the gray background in each td column?

Tags: apache-superset

[Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI4Gy.png)

How do I delete the gray background in each `td` column ?

I don't understand why the visualization is like that, it's so hard to read the value and interrupting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is just a result in table  default format